# Get selected option attributes using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom

My goal is to collect all the values from the selected option into a state. How to do it correctly? I thought about how to refer to the attributes of the selected option, but I did not succeed.
I have the following State

```js
  const [search, setSearch] = useState({
    phone: "",
    mark: "",
    model: "",
    name: "",
  })
```

Here is my onChange function

```js
  const onSearchChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }))
  }
```

And there is a Select mapping values from an object. So such values as `{it.name}, {it.mark}, {it.model}` and so on I want to collect in the `search` state

```html
<select
  className="block appearance-none w-full"
  value={search}
  name="search"
  id="searchBlock"
  onChange={onSearchChange}>
  {customerList.map((it) => {
    return (
      <option
       value={it.name}
       phone={it.phone}>
        {it.name}, {it.mark} {it.model} {it.regnumber}, {it.phone} 
      </option>
    )
  })}
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like:

```js
function SelectApp() {
  const [search, setSearch] = React.useState(0);
  const onSearchChange = (e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    setSearch(value);
  };
  const customerList = [
    { name: "John", model: "x", regnumber: 23, phone: "+145623455" },
    { name: "Niil", model: "box", regnumber: 44, phone: "+185823499" },
    { name: "Jerry", model: "box", regnumber: 44, phone: "+188823499" }
  ];
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        className="block appearance-none w-full"
        defaultValue={customerList[search]}
        name="search"
        id="searchBlock"
        onChange={onSearchChange}
      >
        {customerList.map((it, key) => {
          return (
            <option value={key}>
              {it.name}, {it.mark} {it.model} {it.regnumber}, {it.phone}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So you can get the values from the list on the key changes

Answer (score 0):

If you will create an object before to set on the state, so it would be like the following example...

```
 const onSearchChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    let newComboBoxValue = {}

    newComboBoxValue[name] = newComboBoxValue[value];
    setState((prevState) => ({
      ...prevState,
      newComboBoxValue
    }))
  }
```

Good luck!!

CLC